# Here.com Route API - V8 - State Mileage

Tags: here-api

We're trying to migrate from routes v7 to routes v8. Using v8, how can we get a breakdown of miles per US State?

In version 7.2 we could do

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=API_KEY&mode=fastest;truck&excludecountries=MEX,CAN&metricSystem=imperial&routeattributes=sm,sc&instructionFormat=text&truckType=tractorTruck&trailersCount=1&waypoint0=geo!33.90251,-81.13206&waypoint1=geo!39.80203,-105.08759

And the state codes would be in the summaryByCountry element:

```
"summaryByCountry": [
    {
        "distance": 189887,
        "trafficTime": 8239,
        "baseTime": 8206,
        "flags": [
            "motorway",
            "builtUpArea"
        ],
        "text": "The trip takes 118 mi and 2:17 h.",
        "travelTime": 8206,
        "country": "South Carolina",
        "_type": "RouteSummaryByCountryType"
    },
...
```

In version 8, a similar request:

[https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=API_KEY&origin=32.20618,-110.96474&destination=40.391537,-104.681168&routingMode=fast&transportMode=truck&avoid[features]=ferry&exclude[countries]=MEX,CAN&units=imperial&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions&spans=countryCode,length,truckAttributes,notices&truck[trailerCount]=1&via=40.014984,-105.270546](https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=API_KEY&origin=32.20618,-110.96474&destination=40.391537,-104.681168&routingMode=fast&transportMode=truck&avoid%5Bfeatures%5D=ferry&exclude%5Bcountries%5D=MEX,CAN&units=imperial&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions&spans=countryCode,length,truckAttributes,notices&truck%5BtrailerCount%5D=1&via=40.014984,-105.270546)

```
"spans": [
    {
        "offset": 0,
        "truckAttributes": [
            "open"
        ],
        "length": 1460740,
        "countryCode": "USA"
    },
    {
        "offset": 14050,
        "truckAttributes": [
            "open",
            "tollRoad"
        ],
        "length": 272,
        "countryCode": "USA"
    },
    {
        "offset": 14053,
        "truckAttributes": [
            "open"
        ],
        "length": 23153,
        "countryCode": "USA"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v7: summaryByCountry
v8: Not present. If spans are requested with spans=countryCode,length, then information about the distance in each country can be retrieved. No plans to support in any other manner.
Response in v8 contains :

```
spans": [
                    {
                        "offset": 0,
                        "truckAttributes": [
                            "open"
                        ],
                        "length": 76817,
                        "countryCode": "USA"
                    }
                ],
```

link to migration guide : https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html